# Run command with sudo by default

Tags: sudo, root, alias, privileges

I need a linux user (lets call him "bob") who is allowed to run a list of commands which require root privileges. So let him be required to run `/sbin/firstcommand` and `/sbin/secondcommand` (which are part of the infamous bob-daemon¹) as root, as in `sudo firstcommand`. Without having to input a password.

This is what I've done to `/etc/sudoers` so far:

```
Cmnd_Alias BOBCOMMANDS = /sbin/firstcommand, /sbin/secondcommand
bob        ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:BOBCOMMANDS
```

This leads to `bob$ sudo firstcommand` and `bob$ sudo secondcommand` successfully be run as root, but leaves no way to run i.e. `bob$ sudo mount ... ...`, even with providing a password, which feels perfect to me.

Now, I want the aforementioned bob-daemon¹ to run as user `bob` rather than `root`, because it only needs those privileges for the `BOBCOMMANDS`. In fact, whenever the `bob$ firstcommand` is issued, I want `bob$ sudo firstcommand` to be executed.

Looked to me like an alias could fix this: `bob$ alias firstcommand="sudo firstcommand"; alias secondcommand="sudo secondcommand"` actually worked, but I failed to make the aliases persistent without bob having a home directory.

The last thing I should mention is that this should be easily deployable to multiple machines, so I would prefer not to touch linux' existing system files, apart from having to create bob and changing `sudoers`.

Any solutions?

---

¹ simplified by me

Comment: How you start the daemon; with systemd ? or is it possible to set it up with systemd units?

Answer (score 1):

You said the commands the user needs to run with root privileges are `/sbin/firstcommand` and `/sbin/secondcommand`?

If those commands are indeed located in `/sbin`, that is a directory which is not included in the regular user `PATH` by default. You can use this to your advantage: you could create two very simple scripts `/usr/local/bin/firstcommand` and `/usr/local/bin/secondcommand`, whose contents would essentially be just the `sudo /sbin/firstcommand` and `sudo /sbin/secondcommand` respectively.

The user's shell will normally look for `/usr/local/bin` before the standard `/usr/bin` and `/bin`, allowing the system administrator to override the standard system commands with local versions if necessary. In much the same way, when the user runs `firstcommand`, they'll end up running whichever version of `firstcommand` can be found first in their `PATH`... which can be a script of your choosing that runs the real `/sbin/firstcommand` prefixed with `sudo` and/or with some parameters appended as necessary.

The actual program files and other system files won't need to be modified at all, other than for the configuration of the necessary `sudo` access.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a daemon, the standard way of doing things is to put something like this in the init script file:

```
USER=bob
...
su -c '/command/to/start/actual/daemon' "$USER"
```

In the script file that should be run as `bob`, just put `sudo` in front of the pertinent commands.

Also, make sure you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615877/why-aliases-in-a-non-interactive-bash-shell-do-not-work) about enabling alias expansion in non-interactive Bash shells (e.g. the ones started by a script or daemon).

Comment: Actually, the daemon handles user switching itself - started up as root, it does some bootstraps before forking and continuing to run as `bob`. Plus, I did not create the daemon and would like to avoid patching it for the sake of updatability …